# Java House Applet

Tags: java

So I'm just starting with Applets and I am making a house with an open door and 2 open windows when the applet loads. When you click these windows or door then they will shut. My question though is what do I need to do to re-open these windows doors. I figure I need to set the Boolean variables to False somehow and repaint. Where would I do this. I don't need you guys to write the code for me, I just want to know what I should do.

Thanks ahead of time,

Rick

```
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import java.applet.*;

/**
Rick Armstrong
Chapter 14 - House Applet
*/

   public class HouseApplet extends Applet {    
  boolean leftWin, rightWin, door;

  public void init()      
  {      
     leftWin = false;
     rightWin = false;
     door = false;      

     setBackground(Color.white);       
     addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());       
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
     super.paint(g);

    // Draw the house.
     g.setColor(Color.black);
     g.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 100);

    // Draw the roof
     g.drawLine(80, 100, 320, 100);
     g.drawLine(80, 100, 200, 40);
     g.drawLine(200, 40, 320, 100);

    // Draw the left window open.
     g.fillRect(120, 130, 40, 40);

    // Draw the right window open.
     g.fillRect(240, 130, 40, 40);

    // Draw the door open.
     g.fillRect(180, 130, 40, 70);          

     if (leftWin) {
        // Draw the left window closed.
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(120, 130, 40, 40);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(120, 130, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(140, 130, 140, 170);
        g.drawLine(120, 150, 160, 150);

     }

     if (rightWin) {
        // Draw the right window closed.
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(240, 130, 40, 40);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(240, 130, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(260, 130, 260, 170);
        g.drawLine(240, 150, 280, 150);

     }

     if (door) {
        // Draw the door closed.
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(180, 130, 40, 70);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(180, 130, 40, 70);
        g.fillOval(210, 165, 07, 07);

     }    
  }

  private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener
  {
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
     {
     }

     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
     {
        int currentx = e.getX();
        int currenty = e.getY();

        boolean WindowLeft = (currentx >= 120 && currentx < 160 && currenty >= 130 && currenty <= 170);
        if (WindowLeft)
        {
           leftWin = true;
           repaint();               
        }

        boolean WindowRight = (currentx >= 240 && currentx < 280 && currenty >= 130 && currenty <= 170);
        if (WindowRight)
        {
           rightWin = true;
           repaint(); 
        }

        boolean Door = (currentx >= 180 && currentx < 220 && currenty >= 40 && currenty <= 200);
        if (Door)
        {            
           door = true;
           repaint();     
        }  

        else;  
     }

     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
     {
     }

     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
     {
     }

     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
     {
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but why are you always setting the values to true in the event handler?

If you want a toggling behavior, you could simply write: `value = !value` and then repaint.
Since you initially set your value to false, the next click would set it to true, the next to false, etc. etc.

For example:

```
if (WindowLeft)
        {
           leftWin = !leftWin;
           repaint();               
        }
```

Note that it is possible for you to cause sort of a "race condition" by clicking faster than the framework has a chance to update the view, but this is usually not a problem for initial problem.

BTW: In terms of readability, consider naming your variables in a way that conveys their meaning. For example, is the naming door evocative of a boolean? not really. but doorOpen is, and it helps interpret the meaning of the variable and its transitions.

Comment: good question. It sounded good when I wrote it haha. I'll give that a try Uri. Thank you for the respons.

Comment: ya there is a few things I could have done different Uri, I'm not denying that haha. But after you told me value = !value; then it all made sense to me. I felt rather dumb after you posted it. I knew it was something easy like that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (WindowRight)
{
    rightWin = false;
    repaint(); 
}
else {
    rightWin = true;
    repaint(); 
}
```

try the above. When you click inside the window, it closes otherwise it opens